# Android: Loading Fragment is Slow to Get String Values From SQLite

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I try to use SQLite database to get String values and set these values into TextViews in Fragment.The String values are gotten when Boolean variables are returned true, and when loading the fragment, it takes little bit long time to load.

I have tried to use multiple threads to solve the problem but it does not work apparently. Do you have any idea to be faster load the fragment?

**This is a class that be called in the fragment**

```
public class Schedule_Config_Monday{
private Context mContext;

public Schedule_Config_Monday(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
}

public void Monday_Schedule_Settings_0(final TextView textView_1,final TextView textView_2,final TextView textView_3,final TextView textView_4,final TextView textView_5,
                               final TextView textView_6,final TextView textView_7,final TextView textView_8,final TextView textView_9,final TextView textView_10,
                               final TextView textView_11,final TextView textView_12,final TextView textView_13,final TextView textView_14,final TextView textView_15,
                               final TextView textView_16,final TextView textView_17,final TextView textView_18,final TextView textView_19,final TextView textView_20,
                               final TextView textView_21,final TextView textView_22,final TextView textView_23,final TextView textView_24){

    final DatabaseTimetable databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);

    final boolean[] monday_b = new boolean[]{
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,1),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,2),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,3),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,4),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,5),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,6),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,7),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,8),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,9),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,10),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,11),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,12),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,13),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,14),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,15),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,16),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,17),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,18),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,19),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,20),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,21),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,22),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,23),
            databaseTimetable.Monday_Start_End_Time(0,0)
    };

    final TextView[] Mon_Text = new TextView[]{
            textView_1,textView_2,textView_3,textView_4,textView_5,
            textView_6,textView_7,textView_8,textView_9,textView_10,
            textView_11,textView_12,textView_13,textView_14,textView_15,
            textView_16,textView_17,textView_18,textView_19,textView_20,
            textView_21,textView_22,textView_23,textView_24};

            final int start = 0;

            if (monday_b[0]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 1;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        Mon_Text[0].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[1]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 2;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[2]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 3;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[3]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 4;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[4]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 5;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[5]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 6;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[6]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 7;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[7]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 8;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[8]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 9;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[9]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 10;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[10]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 11;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[11]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 12;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[12]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 13;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[13]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 14;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[14]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 15;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[15]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 16;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[16]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 17;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[17]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 18;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[18]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 19;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[19]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 20;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[20]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 21;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[21]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 22;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[22]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 23;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (monday_b[23]){
                Mon_Text[0].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int end = 0;
                        Mon_Text[0].setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start,end));
                        Mon_Text[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start,end)));
                        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++){
                            Mon_Text[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start,end)));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
    }
}
```

**These are methods inside of a class extends SQLiteOpenHelper to get Title, Text Color and Background Color**

```
public String Monday_Title(int start, int end){
    sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_TITLE,COLUMN_SUBTITLE,
            COLUMN_MON,COLUMN_START_TIME,COLUMN_END_TIME};
    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_TIMETABLE,columns,COLUMN_MON + "=" + 1 + " AND " + COLUMN_START_TIME + " = " + start + " AND " + COLUMN_END_TIME + " = " + end,null,null,null,null);
    int iTitle = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TITLE);
    int iSubtitle = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SUBTITLE);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
        result.append(cursor.getString(iTitle)).append("\n").append("\n").append(cursor.getString(iSubtitle)).append("\n\n");
    }
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return result.toString();
}

//Monday Get TextColor
public String Monday_Text_Color(int start, int end){
    sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_TITLE,COLUMN_SUBTITLE, COLUMN_COLOR_TEXT,
            COLUMN_MON,COLUMN_START_TIME,COLUMN_END_TIME};
    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_TIMETABLE,columns,COLUMN_MON + "=" + 1 + " AND " + COLUMN_START_TIME + " = " + start + " AND " + COLUMN_END_TIME + " = " + end,null,null,null,null);
    int iTextColor = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_COLOR_TEXT);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
        result.append("#").append(cursor.getString(iTextColor));
    }
    sqLiteDatabase.close();

    return result.toString();
}
//Monday Get Text Background Color
public String Monday_Text_BG_Color(int start, int end){
    sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_TITLE,COLUMN_SUBTITLE, COLUMN_COLOR_TEXT_BG,
            COLUMN_MON,COLUMN_START_TIME,COLUMN_END_TIME};
    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_TIMETABLE,columns,COLUMN_MON + "=" + 1 + " AND " + COLUMN_START_TIME + " = " + start + " AND " + COLUMN_END_TIME + " = " + end,null,null,null,null);
    int iTextColor_BG = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_COLOR_TEXT_BG);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
        result.append("#").append(cursor.getString(iTextColor_BG));
    }
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return result.toString();
}
```

**This is a method that returns true if defined `start` and `end` are in the database**

```
public Boolean Monday_Start_End_Time(int start, int end){
    sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_MON,COLUMN_START_TIME,COLUMN_END_TIME};
    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_TIMETABLE,columns,COLUMN_MON + "=" + 1 + " AND " + COLUMN_START_TIME + " = " + start + " AND " + COLUMN_END_TIME + " = " + end,null,null,null,null);
    boolean result = cursor.moveToFirst();
    cursor.close();
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return result;
}
```

I am currently thinking what makes slow loading fragment is this Boolean check, so that I tried to create a function that returns integer value when the boolean variables are true, but it also slow to load the fragment.

And I am sure the problem is method of `public void Monday_Schedule_Settings_0` because when I remove the code, the fragment loads definitely faster.

I would love to hear you advise.

Answer (score 0):

I think your performance problem is that you're closing the database and reopening it with every DB query. You should be closing the cursors, but not closing the database itself. IE you should remove every instance of:

```
sqliteDatabase.close();
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I have tested with removing `sqliteDatabase.close();` and it improves performance. Thank you very much